# Why is Scrivener using the "First pages" setting for the entire manuscript?

Tags: formatting, scrivener

I have a 'project format' template I've been using for a long time that shows a different header for the Front Matter, then starts the manuscript at Chapter 1 with the project title/page 1 etc in the header. This has stopped working, and is now using the "First pages" header for the entire manuscript.

- The Front Matter is a title page in the Front Matter folder in the Binder
- I am adding the front matter using the "Add front matter" checkbox
- The front matter's section type is 'N/A' (I can't see a more applicable option)

Is there anything obvious I may have missed?

Comment: What formatting is assigned to section type 'N/A'?  —— In compile settings, make sure each document is assigned the appropriate section type and each section type is assigned the appropriate formatting. (I'm using Scrivener in German and don't know what the correct terms are in English.) —— I prefer to ask Scrivener questions in the Literature & Latte forums, as there I can get help by the developers.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix this with the help of someone on the Scrivener forums. I don't know which specific step fixed it, but these were the steps taken:

- Copied the export format to a new format
- Added a new separate section layout for the title page, created a section type for Title Page and assigned the title page section layout to it
- Moved all chapter documents out of sub folders into the main Manuscript folder
- Ensured that the section type was correct for all documents (title page + chapters)

There was no obvious step which suddenly stopped the chapters being treated as front matter, but eventually it started to play ball again. Hope the above helps someone.